# android - drawRectangle colors

Tags: java, android

In my Code are three shapes which are filled with the same color every time. Now I want them to swap their color randomly. How do I get there from here? Right now it sets all shapes the same color, but I want them to use all colors and change the color of the rectangles

I get errors in my code at `usedColors.add(Color.paint);` it says 'The method add(int, Color) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (int)'

At `paint.setColor(usedColors.get(x));` there it gives out 'The method setColor(int) in the type Paint is not applicable for the arguments (String)'

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            private Paint paint = new Paint();

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas();       
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);                                                   
                List<Color> usedColors = new ArrayList<>();
                Random rand = new Random();

        int colorsFound = 0;

        while(colorsFound < 3) {
            int rando = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
            switch (rando) {
                case 1:
                    if (!usedColors.contains("yellow")) {
                        colorsFound++;
                        usedColors.add(Color.YELLOW);
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (!usedColors.contains("green")) {
                        colorsFound++;
                        usedColors.add(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (!usedColors.contains("red")) {
                        colorsFound++;
                        usedColors.add(Color.RED);
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(usedColors.get(0));
        canvas.drawRect((float) ((float) canvas.getWidth()/50), (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.32), canvas.getWidth()/15, (float) (canvas.getHeight()/2.8), paint);

        paint.setColor(usedColors.get(1));
        canvas.drawRect((float) (canvas.getWidth()/1.067), (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.32), (float) (canvas.getWidth()/1.02), (float) (canvas.getHeight()/2.8), paint);

        paint.setColor(usedColors.get(2));
canvas.drawRect((float) (canvas.getWidth()/10), (float) (canvas.getHeight()/3), (float) (canvas.getWidth()/1.1), (float)  (canvas.getHeight()/3.35), green);
```

Comment: Please post a complete example. This means that your code should look like a Java program. In particular, you should have a `class` and a method inside that class which then contains the code you are asking about. Note that this **does not** mean to post every class in your app. Nor does it mean to post the entire class that contains the code you are asking about. It means to post enough code that we have some context for the part you are talking about. As the saying goes, make it as simple as possible but no simpler.

Comment: You're right, sorry

Comment: How do you know when to change the colors? Will the user click on a button? Do you want them to change after a certain amount of time? Or what?

Comment: I have an onTouch event an when the user touches, it should change

Comment: Then you should do the drawing in the `onTouch()` method, too.

Comment: Okay thank you. But how do I set the color randomly to the shapes now?

Comment: The exact same way you are already doing it. You just need to do it for each shape individually rather than for all shapes at once.

Comment: To make it a little easier, you can move your code that chooses a random color into a method. Then you just call the method each time you want a new random color.

Comment: Just be a little bit careful about creating the `Random` object. You should do this only once when your Activity is created. Then reuse the same `Random` object each time you want a new random number.

Comment: Ah okay, to do it for each one seperate sounds logically to me, bit how do I avoid then a doubling of a color?

Comment: You can keep track of which colors have already been chosen. If that color is picked again, discard it and choose a different color.

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep a list of "available colors". When a color is used, remove it from the list.

Comment: How do I keep track of them, with a boolean e.g.?

Comment: Yes, boolean will work. Of course, you will need an array or list, not just a single value.

Comment: I edited the question how I thought I could manage it, but it doen't work neither

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Why do I get an error on the `.add()` and the `paint.setColor()`, are they wrong?

Comment: Your should edit your question to include the exact error message.

Comment: Put everything in the question now, I think

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Patience, young grasshopper. I have edited my question.

Comment: Okay I did as you recommended, but it doesn't fix my two errors, the first one just changed a little as I edited

Comment: Please post a new question

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You have declared

```
ArrayList<String> usedColors ...
```

This list can only contain `String` references. Since `Color.YELLOW` is not a `String` the compiler complains when you try to add it.

The best fix is to store `Color`s in your list:

```
List<Color> usedColors = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now you will have to make appropriate changes to be sure you are always using `Color` objects with the list.

**Original answer**

Right now, you are drawing the rectangles in `onCreate()` which is only called once when the `Activity` is created. In order to change the colors of the rectangles, you need to respond to some event that triggers the change to occur. For example, you can make a button which the user clicks to change the colors or you can create a timer which changes the colors after a certain amount of time. I suggest you do some research on event handling in Android to learn more about how to do this.

You might also look into creating a custom component. This will allow you to encapsulate the drawing functionality into a single class which can be reused as many times as you wish. You can then add more rectangles more easily than with your current design.

Comment: And the custom component sets the colors randomly to the shapes? The point is that I don't want two shapes to habe the same color, that's my problem

Comment: @JoeS No, the custom component should have a method `setColor()` or something similar. Then someone else, like `MainActivity`, chooses the color to use. This design makes it a little more clear that you have to set the color individually on each component. Right now you set the color once for all rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same color, because you do not change Paint color between actual calls of *canvas.drawRect()*

You can add simple method after your *onCreate()* method:

```
   private Paint getRandomColorPaint() {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);   
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] colors = {Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED };
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(colors.length);
        paint.setColor(colors[randomNumber]);
        return paint;
    }
```

And then call:

```
canvas.drawRect( ..same here.., getRandomColorPaint(paint));
```

In this case all the three shapes will have randdom colors (but they can be the same with some probability). It would be better to create array of colors in your resourses file, but here I've just provided an example.

You can add a button and add *onClickListener()* and update all shapes there, if you want them change color dynamically.

Comment: I edited the question and use an array now. I want to avoid doubling colors

Comment: Still, the probles is that you are using the same Paint object for all the calls of canvas.drawRect(). I updated my answer a little. Add this method and call it in your drawRect() method instead of just passing paint there.

Comment: The key change is that you should create different paint objects, so rectangles have different colors. This method should help you in this case.

Comment: But how do I set up different color objects in a method?

Comment: The switch-case is not necessary anymore with your code, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it isn't. But my method doesn't guarantee you that all colors will be different, it just picks random one. It may be simply updated to return only unique ones.
Try to apply this method first.

Comment: I' trying to use it, I get no errors but with this code my R.java file isn't created

Comment: Rebuild project. It is in main menu, then Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: I tried to implement it in a new project, guess it has the same effect? Same problem anyway, no R. File created